# Wordpress Ajax and REST API response shows data with cached result WP Engine

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, api, rest

I have created custom REST API and in response i am getting old data result. I am using WP Engine and cache is enabled in the wp-config.php file. I don't want to disable cache, just want my api respone without cached data result. I tried to set header `Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0`, `ob_flush()`, `clearstatcache()` but still having same issue. Also, in my ajax request when i return html data, it shows me old entries. I cross checked in database, it have the correct values but response of ajax and api request are the previous one. When i clear cache from the WP Engine settings on Dashboard then i am getting correct result in ajax and api response.

Here is my code api code

```
  register_rest_route( PLUGIN_DIRNAME.'/v1', '/data/status', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => array( $this, 'get_status' )
));

public function get_status($request){
                $response = array();
                $progress = get_option('progress_percentage');
                $name = get_option('form_submission');
                $response["progress"] = $progress;
                $response["form_id"] = $name;
                if($progress == '100'){
                    $response["submission_status"] = __( 'successfull');
                }
                $result = new WP_REST_Response( $response, 200);
                $result->set_headers( array(
                    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0'
                ) );
                return $result;
    }
```

In ajax response :

```
   function ajax_response(){
                $progress = get_option('progress_percentage');
                if($progress == "100"){
                        $name = get_option('form_submission');
                        $submission_status  = "<div class='complete'>Form submission successfull.</div>";
                }
                return array(
                    'message' => get_option('submission_stage'),
                    'html' => $submission_status,
                );
            }
```

Can anyone help me with this issue. I am struggling with this issue from 4 hours. It would be great help if anyone suggestion made my code working.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i managed to get this issue fixed. I am posting here if in case anyone face the similar issue. I used `wp_cache_flush()` in the begining of api callback function and in the ajax request callback function. It fixed the cache issue for me.